# Using List<ClassName> abc = new ArrayList<ClassName>();

Tags: android, list

This is the Tuple Class

```
public class Tuple
{
    String name;
    String phone;

    public Tuple(String name,String phone)
        {
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
        }
}
```

This is the method to print the List

```
    public void printList(List<Tuple> contact_list)
{
    for(int i=0;i<contact_list.size();i++)
    {
        Log.d("Contact List",contact_list.get(i).toString());

    }
}
```

I am adding the contents in the List like this

contact_list.add(new Tuple(name,number));//name and number are both strings

When I call the method printList i get the output like this

Contact List  com.example.eh.ContactList$Tuple@41b04c28

How do i get the values stored in the list

I want to store the name and number together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the toSting() method in your class:

```
public class Tuple {
     public String toString() {
          return "name=" + name + ", phone=" +phone'
     }
...
```

What you are seeing is the default implementation of "toString()" from java.lang.Object which simply outputs information about the object itself.  By overriding this method, you can provide a representation of the object that is more meaningful to you.  What I have posted above is just one suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
com.example.eh.ContactList$Tuple@41b04c28
```

is the string representation of your class - if you want to have it represented differently you have to override its toString() method.

```
 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
    return "name: " + this.name + " phone: " + this.phone;
 }
```

to get the fields seperately you should implement getter Methods for your fields like

```
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}
```